# Optimal way to calculate no.of ways to move from node i to i in less than k steps

Tags: optimization, graph, matrix-multiplication

I have a n*n undirected graph. I have to find no of ways to move from some node to same in less than k steps. I need a approach faster than k*n^3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do a modified version of A* from the start node back to itself. All you would have to do is change the end conditions.

So, instead of ending once you reach the goal node, you only end once you reach k steps. You'll start with i->i with cost of zero, and then expand child nodes according to A*. In all of these subsequent steps, if you reach the goal, record the path; if you are still under the limit of k steps, keep expanding nodes and print the path when i is reached.

Once you reach the limit of k steps, end the loop.

EDIT: I guess I didn't explain why I would go with A*. If you are unfamiliar with A* ([you can read more here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)), it is a best-first search algorithm. This means its going to pick the best node in the set of available nodes to build the path (best meaning shortest distance to goal). This is done based on known costs of visited nodes, and a guess to how far away the goal is (usually done with euclidean distance).

The reason I think A* would be great for this problem, is because you already know you are at the goal, so it is essentially working backwards for you, finding the next best paths until you tell it to stop or it expands all the nodes in the graph.

Comment: I think this approach has too much complexity.

Comment: Howso? I guess a greedy best-first search could work too, but I wasn't sure if there would be cases in which this would miss a possible path.